# c# Integration testing with Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, integration-testing, localdb, oracle-xe

I have a c# application that can be configured to either use a MS-SQL or Oracle Database.

There are integration tests for MS-SQL that use a local database (LocalDB).
I can easily get the database into the state I need for testing.

Now I want to have similar integration tests for Oracle. Is there a similar kind of local
oracle server? So that I can access that local oracle server from .net to configure it for testing?
Or what is the best approach for integration tests with an oracle database?

**Update:**
Just found out about Oracle XE. Can it be used for my test approach in a similar way then LocalDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't think there is such thing for oracle. oracle xe is just a standard oracle with some limitations, not a dedicated tool to make developer's life easier. so you will have to create code that manages the database lifecycle: create-drop schema, users, import data, start/stop db, grant permissions etc. Some of those (like start/stop, permissions) can be done manually only once per developer. the whole lifecycle is not very difficult to wire into your tests but requires a bit of work and thinking upfront. from the beginning think about speed, e.g. don't recreate schema before each test: just truncate and re-import your data